# I want use LayoutParams to let ViewFlipper MATCH_PARENT but fail

Tags: java, android

I use ViewFlipper and I hope my each of my image will match_parent.
but  my program shut down when I add this line.

```
 ViewFlipper.LayoutParams params = new ViewFlipper.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

when I delete this line ,app run,but image can not match_parent....

this is my code:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context=".Comic"
tools:showIn="@layout/comic">
<ViewFlipper
    android:id="@+id/viewflipper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/st01_1"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</RelativeLayout>
 </ViewFlipper>
</FrameLayout>
```

and this is test.java:

```
viewflipper=(ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.viewflipper);

    viewflipper.addView(getImageView(R.drawable.st01_1),1);
    viewflipper.addView(getImageView(R.drawable.st01_2),2);

//


  private ImageView getImageView(int id){
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new 
FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 
 ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
    imageView.setImageResource(id);
    viewflipper.addView(imageView);
    return imageView;
}
```

how can I do?
please help me ,thanks

Comment: you don't need to add LayoutParams to your ViewFlipper. If you want your ImageView to be match parent then try android:scaleType="fillXY". Hope it works!.

Comment: Vatsal Patel,is it add in test.xml? I add but still not work.....

Comment: Please refer this : https://tutorialwing.com/create-android-viewflipper-programmatically-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your imageView like this.! You need to provide params to your imageView.

```
ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT); 
imageView.setLayoutParams(params);
imageView.setImageResource(image);
viewFlipper.addView(imageView);
```

Also, Remove LayoutParams for your ViewFliper

```
ViewFlipper.LayoutParams params = new ViewFlipper.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
```

Comment: hello,I have change my code on my post,I try ,but still not work.....

Comment: I slove the problem,thank,I finally add these line: imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP); and success